# I need to get a variable between jQuery function and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons on the form I'm getting, this first piece of coce allow me to know which was the button clicked by getting the id of it.

```
var button;
var form = $('.register_ajax');

$('#vote_up, #vote_down').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

and this other send the form data through AJAX using the info already obtained from the button using the script above.

```
form.bind('submit',function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form.serialize() + '&' + encodeURI(button.attr('name')) + '=' + encodeURI(button.attr('value')) ,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //$("#validation-errors").hide().empty();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.message == 0){
                $("#fave").attr('src','interactions/favorite.png');
                $("#favorite").attr('value',1);
                console.log(data.errors);
            }
            if(data.message == 1)
            {
                $("#fave").attr('src','interactions/favorite_active.png');
                $("#favorite").attr('value',0);
            }
            if(data.message == "plus")
            {
                $("#vote_up").attr('class','options options-hover');
                $("#vote_down").attr('class','options');
                console.log(data.message);
            }
            if(data.message == "sub")
            {
                $("#vote_down").attr('class','options options-hover');
                $("#vote_up").attr('class','options');
                console.log("sub");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

The problem is that the data is not being passed to the ajax function, the button info is being saved on the button var, but it's not being obtained at time on the ajax call to work with it (or at least that is what I think). I'd like to know what can I do to make this work, any help appreciated.

**1st edit:** If I get the button data directly  like `button = $('#vote_up');` it doesn't work either, it only works if I get the button directly like this but without using the function.

**2nd edit:** I found the solution, I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution, I just changed a little bit the click function like this:

```
var button;
var form = $('.register_ajax');
var data = form.serializeArray();
$('#vote_up, #vote_down').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button = $(this).attr("id");
    data.push({name: encodeURI($(this).attr('name')), value: encodeURI($(this).attr('value'))});
    form.submit();
});
```

using `e.preventDefault();` and `form.submit();` to send the form. also I changed the data.serialize to `serializeArray();` because it's more effective to push data into the serializeArray(). in the second script I just changed the data.serialize() and used the data variable that I already filled with the serializeArray() and the data.push():

```
form.bind('submit',function () {
    alert(button);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,

        //here goes the rest of the code
        //...
});
return false;
});
```

it worked for me, it solved the problem between the click and submit event that wasn't allowing me to send the function through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

`var button` is in the scope of the `.on('event', function(){})`

You need to declare the variable in the shared scope, then you can modify the value inside the event callback, i.e.

```
var button,
    form = $('.register_ajax');

$('#vote_up, #vote_down').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    button = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: I did what you explain here, but this isn't working either, i'm not getting anything from the console, and the queries aren't being executed.

Comment: Add a console.log(button) in the event function- button === attr 'id', but in the $.ajax function looking for the attr name . Maybe try making button = attr 'name'...

Comment: SO is a place where you can find people who will help you solve problems. If you want someone to just solve problems for you, you need to pay someone .

Answer (score 0):

You are being victim of a clousure. Just as adam_bear said you need to declare the variable outside of the function where you are setting it, but you are going to keep hitting these kind of walls constantly unless you dedicate some hours to learn the Good Parts :D, javascript is full of these type of things, [here is a good book for you](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) and you can also learn more from the author at http://www.crockford.com/.

Comment: yes I saw the problem, but it wasn't the problem. thanks for the book.